# Distinct Count of multiple columns SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, distinct

I have searched and "researched" to no avail.  Just looking to clean up this code:

```
select COUNT(distinct ecd.fnlfc) fc,
       COUNT(distinct ecd.fnlprimpyr) primpyr, 
       COUNT(distinct ecd.FnlPrimPyrHlthPlanId) primpyrhlthplanid, 
       COUNT(distinct ecd.FnlRptGrpMne) rptgrpmne,
       COUNT(distinct ecd.FnlPyrCat) fnlpyrcat, 
       COUNT(distinct ecd.FnlPyrCatDtl) fnlpyrcatdtl, 
       COUNT(distinct ecd.PyrHlthPlanName1) hlthplanname1,
       COUNT(distinct ecd.PyrHlthPlanRptGrpMne1) hlthplanrptgrpmne1, 
       COUNT(distinct ecd.PyrHlthPlanCat1) hlthplancat1, 
       COUNT(distinct ecd.PyrHlthPlanCatDtl1) hlthplancatdtl1

from Table1
```

I simply need a distinct count of each of these fields.  I don't need to see any of the fields' values.  Ideally, the output would be:

```
fnlfc         9
fnlprimpyr    22
...
```

Comment: Your query looks fine.  I would use `as` before a column alias, but that is not necessary.

Comment: your query is a good as it an be, except you're missing the table alias: `from Table1 ecd`

Comment: except they will be presented as columns and the number shown beneath the column heading. If you have to have rows you need more. do you really need sql to produce that multi-row output?

Comment: ok, thanks folks.  didn't know if i could remove some redundancy there.  no, i don't necessarily need the multi-row.  only if it was easy :)